# How to Bind to Height with "auto" value

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10

Working with UWP means I cant use DIP values always. I rely on "auto" sizes, "Stretch" alignments, etc.
I narrowed my problem to this:

How Can I Bind Height and Width of Element to Another Element, which has Height and Width "Auto"?

Sample:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="CardGriddRow1" Height="2*" />
            <RowDefinition x:Name="CardGrdidRow2" Height="1*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Rectangle Name="Rec1" Fill="Blue"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="auto" Height="auto" Grid.Row="1" Margin="20" />
        <Rectangle Name="Rec2" Fill="Yellow" Grid.Row="0" Height="{x:Bind Rec1.ActualHeight, Mode=OneWay  }" Width="{x:Bind Rec1.ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay }"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  />
```

When using ActualHeight, I can use only OneWay mode. Height value is NaN.
Rec2 will have 0 values but ActualHeight of Rec1 is more than 0.

Is there way to force Binding to take ActualHeight?

Comment: Can you give more information about why you need to be able to do this, because the code shown and the description given doesn't really explain why you would need to do this? (There may be a way for you to set up your xaml without having to set the Height and Width to that of another element)

Comment: @ jsmyth886 I'm making a simple card game. Sample Picture (a simple placeholder really):
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dFW9zu1vYKXr_Fo2FuKnNyUcOcAAO3Rh/view)
In the bottom row there are 8 cards in the grid, which has allways fill the entire width of the screen.
These cards can be in two rows, one row above the other, when narrow screen. This is handled by VisualStateManager.
In the Upper middle, there are two packs of cards, which are the same size as the bottom cards. I want to do this only in XAML, but binding is not working properly.  I was hoping, I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to avoid the `SizeChanged` event as much as possible as it fires so often when the screen is resized it can cause the UI to start freezing and drop in frame rate. Let the Xaml do as much of the work as possible. I've recreated the scenario you've shown in the link you attached in your comment using Xaml only. See screenshot:[image]

It may not be exactly the same as yours but with some styling it could be.

See code:

```
<Page>
  <Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
      <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
              Value="Stretch"/>
      <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
              Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
  </Page.Resources>
  <Grid Background="Blue">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Grid Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="8">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0"
               Grid.Column="1"
               Fill="Red" />
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0"
               Grid.Column="2"
               Fill="Yellow" />
  </Grid>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="2"
               Grid.Column="0"
               Fill="Blue" />
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="2"
               Grid.Column="1"
               Fill="Red" />
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="2"
               Grid.Column="2"
               Fill="Green" />
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="2"
               Grid.Column="3"
               Fill="Yellow" />
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="2"
               Grid.Column="4"
               Fill="Brown" />
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="2"
               Grid.Column="5"
               Fill="Pink" />
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="2"
               Grid.Column="6"
               Fill="Purple" />
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="2"
               Grid.Column="7"
               Fill="Orange" />
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: This solution, to split page into cells to match top and bottom row, is bit hard to use, since page layout will be a lot more complicated, but I can play with it, with a lot of Column and Row Spans.
Still, I hoped for a little better possibilities from XAML.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> How Can I Bind Height and Width of Element to Another Element, which has Height and Width "Auto"?

`ActualHeight` is a calculated property. For purposes of `ElementName` binding, `ActualHeight` does not post updates when it changes (due to its asynchronous and run-time calculated nature). Do not attempt to use `ActualHeight` as a binding source for an `ElementName` binding. If you have a scenario that requires updates based on `ActualHeight`, use a `SizeChanged` handler. Details please reference [`ActualHeight`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement#Windows_UI_Xaml_FrameworkElement_ActualHeight) property.

Although updated your code snippet to use binding instead as follows, it seems like worked , but it is not reliable that you should not use it .

```
 <Rectangle Name="Rec1" Fill="Blue"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Grid.Row="1" Margin="20" Height="auto" Width="auto" />
 <Rectangle Name="Rec2" Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight,ElementName=Rec1}" Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth,ElementName=Rec1}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"   Fill="Yellow" Grid.Row="0"/>
```

The correct way as the document mentioned, you could use [`SizeChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement#Windows_UI_Xaml_FrameworkElement_SizeChanged), for example:

```
<Rectangle Name="Rec1" SizeChanged="Rec1_SizeChanged" Fill="Blue"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Grid.Row="1" Margin="20" Height="auto" Width="auto" />
<Rectangle Name="Rec2" Fill="Yellow" Grid.Row="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  />
```

Code behind:

```
private void Rec1_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Rec2.Height = Rec1.ActualHeight;
    Rec2.Width = Rec1.ActualWidth;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation, it helpt me to understand the problem. 
The first solution works on launch of page, but afterwards it does not resize the rectangle. For SizeChanged, I dont want to use event handlers for graphic layout, if not really necessary.

Comment: @MadMaxIV in that case I would look at my answer below. It showcases how you can set up your Xaml in such a way that whilst resizing the app it should in theory "just work" without any SizeChanged nastiness.